# Hibernate Query API and Java 1.5/Generics

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

All APIs in Hibernate are from 1.4 and are thus not using java generics.

So I wonder how "safe" the following is: (preconditions: name column is of datatype String, or atleast compatible to String)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getAll() {
    Query q = session.createQuery(
        "select name from Customers");
    return q.list();    
}
```

From the Queryi API (org.hibernate.Query.list()) javadoc.

["Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[]. "](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be safe as long as you are sure that the query does not "contain multiple results per row". (I'm not familiar with queries, so I am unsure whether it can happen in this case.) If a row does contain multiple results, then when you try to access it, it will throw ClassCastException at runtime because that element will be an Object[] object instead of a String object.

Comment: That can happen if for example you have a hbm query with joins like this: `from Item i left join i.preferences p where p is null`. Here it will select both item and it's preferences rows so you will get the multiple results. To avoid that you would need to specify that you want only items to be returned: `select i from Item i left join i.preferences p where p is null`

Answer (score 3):

Java generics use type erasure, so at runtime there's no difference between a `List`, a `List<String>`, and a `List<Integer>`. All are really just `List`s. At compilation, the compiler will enforce the template parameter type, but under the covers at runtime, you a have a `List`.

In fact, if you try to use reflection to find the template parameter type, you can't.

Comment: (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()   .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

how you get your template parameter

Answer (score 2):

In Java, generics actually are erasures, which is nothing but compiler magic. The types used as generic type arguments are unknown at runtime. Therefore, the cast should be successful if the list returned implements the List interface, but the compiler may throw warnings at you.

Comment: Sure, that cast will be successful, but I think that's missing the point. When when you try to actually get objects out of the list, you want to be sure they are actually `String`s.

Comment: @MatrixFrog, this assumption will be enforced at runtime by the casts which are generated by the compiler. Note that the author has explicitly stated that the objects in the array would be strings.